# Why I can’t access to internet with this vpn setup?

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, openvpn

I try to setup a vpn between 2 networks over internet following this link https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/

On my server

- openvpn runs
- port 1194 transfered
- interface ; inet 10.9.8.1 peer 10.9.8.2/32 scope global tun0

On my client

- interface : inet 10.9.8.10 peer 10.9.8.9/32 scope global tun0
- routes (ip r)

> ```
> default via 10.9.8.9 dev tun0 
> 10.0.3.0/24 dev lxcbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.1 linkdown 
> 10.9.8.0/24 via 10.9.8.9 dev tun0 
> 10.9.8.9 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.8.10 
> <my.server.wan.ip> via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp3s0 proto static 
> 169.254.0.0/16 dev tun0 scope link metric 1000 
> 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.156 metric 600
> ```

From my client, I can access my server from my tun0 interface (ssh 10.9.8.1 → my server)

But I cannot access internet from my client (ping 8.8.8.8 does not work)

I missed st but don’t see what. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tcpdump** will be very helpful here.
Run it on both nodes and reach out to an IP address that you know, best is a site with a static IP.
Then you can run

```
tcpdump -nni any host (the IP)
```

example output on an icmp ping to 8.8.8.8:

```
#tcpdump -nni any host 8.8.8.8
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length     262144 bytes
13:28:08.141937 enp2s0 Out IP 192.168.200.200 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo     request, id 47151, seq 1, length 64
13:28:08.150955 enp2s0 In  IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.200.200: ICMP echo reply,     id 47151, seq 1, length 64
```

It can tell you which interface the traffic is leaving (Out) as well as received (In).

- On the client, it should enter the tunnel ("interface name" **Out**).
- On the server, you should see the traffic arriving ("interface name" **In**).

If your server receives the traffic destined for Internet, then your server might not be routing, that is, to forward packets according to certain rules (iptables for example).
Since I don't see it explicitly mentioned in your given link, see if this helps as an example ([external link to tecadmin](https://tecadmin.net/setting-up-a-port-forwarding-using-iptables-in-linux/)) to set the server up as a router.

Comment: Thank @boro for your reply, I'm not used with tcpdump and did know how to begin, I'll try with your advices and let you know ...

Comment: Right I have to setup IP forwarding & masquerading